# How to hide a jQuery manipulated empty element and its parent

Tags: jquery, children

I have a form (todo list) containing labels/checkboxes (todos) as follows:

```
<form class="tasklist">
    These are your tasks for today
    <label>
        <input class="task" type="checkbox">
        This is a task that was added by the user
     </label>
     <label>
        <input class="task" type="checkbox">
        This is a task that was added by the user
     </label>
 </form>
```

When a user checks a task it is removed (both the input and the parent label) from the DOM using the following Javascript:

```
$('input.task').click(function(){
    var checkbox = $(this);
    if (checkbox.prop("checked")) {
       checkbox.parent().css('text-decoration', 'line-through').fadeOut(1000, function(){checkbox.parent().remove();});
    }
});
```

I want the parent form (.tasklist) to disappear once it has no more tasks (label children). I am rather new to jQuery and I tried various methods to no avail (.tasklist:empty, children('label').size() == 0 etc...)

EDIT: Please note that there may be more than one tasklist form.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with the code you gave us, I just added `form.children().length == 0`.

```
$('input.task').click(function(){
  var checkbox = $(this);
  var form = $(this).parents('form');
  if (checkbox.prop("checked")) {
     checkbox.parent().css('text-decoration', 'line-through').fadeOut(1000, function(){
         checkbox.parent().remove();
         if(form.children().length == 0) {
           form.remove();
         }
     });
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kuroir/zQTGW/)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think the inputs should be outside of the labels.</strike>
edit:
Ok, i just checked, they can be inside labels, but a downvote for that? Really? A comment would have done, but it's not as fun i suppose.

---

Anyway you could do it like that:

```
if($('.tasklist label').length == 0){
    $('.tasklist').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example (using hide instead of removal)
Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/BpFJY/

```
$('input.task').click(function(){
  var checkbox = $(this);
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
     checkbox.parent().css('text-decoration', 'line-through').fadeOut(1000, function(){
         checkbox.parent().hide();
     });
  }
  if ($('.tasklist input:not(:checked)').length == 0)
      $('.tasklist').hide();
});
```

Comment: This works when there is a single form in the page, but not when there is more than one. I apologize for forgetting to mention this in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the 1st edit.. I have fixed the code and provided and example of it working

You could add a number to each form like so

```
<form class="tasklist-1">
 </form>

<span>Next Form</span>

<form class="tasklist-2">
 </form>
```

Then use this to check if the form is submitted!

```
$('input.task').click(function(){
  var checkbox = $(this);
  var form = $(this).parents('form');
  var fid = form.attr("class").replace("tasklist-","");
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
     checkbox.parent().css('text-decoration', 'line-through').fadeOut(1000, function(){
         checkbox.parent().hide();
     });
  }
  if ($('.tasklist-' + fid + ' input:not(:checked)').length == 0)
      $('.tasklist-' + fid).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Live Example
http://jsfiddle.net/RQjhN/1/